# How do I access a shapefile using gdal?

Tags: python, gdal, qgis

I am trying to use the following code to access a shapefile:

```py
import os
from osgeo import gdal
from osgeo import ogr
from osgeo import osr

shp_path = "xxxxxxxx"
if __name__=='__main__':
    ogr.RegisterAll()
    gdal.SetConfigOption("SHAPE_ENCODING", "UTF-8")
    gdal.SetConfigOption("GDAL_FILENAME_IS_UTF8", "YES") 
    oDriver = ogr.GetDriverByName("ESRI Shapefile")
    path_list= os.listdir(shp_path)
    for dir in path_list:
        if dir.endswith('.shp'):
            oDS = oDriver.Open(dir, 0)
            iLayerCount = oDS.GetLayerCount()
            out_lyr = oDS.GetLayerByIndex(0)
            print(dir, iLayerCount, out_lyr.schema.len(), out_lyr.schema[0].name)
```

I got one result like this:

`"GBZ2012371002CZ.shp",1,1,'Item_Code'`

However, when I access this shape file in QGIS, by opening its attribute table, I know it actually has a lot of fields as follows: [fields in QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUEHL.png)
So, I begin to doubt if I am accessing the right part of the shapefile, and question what is the relation between gdal layer and what I see in QGIS.

Environment:

- QGIS: 3.26.3
- PYTHON: 3.7.9 (64-bit)
- GDAL: 3.0.4

Actually the 'Item_Code' field is a result of my former code. That is when I unproperly used [Driver.CreateDataSource](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Driver) instead of [Driver.Open](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.Driver) to try to load the file. At that time I used [DataSource.CreateLayer](https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.ogr.html#osgeo.ogr.DataSource) to create layer and added the field 'Item_Code'. So, essentially I haven't gotten the right method to access the data I want, that is to say, the data shown in the QGIS attribute table.

I tried to switch the shp_path to another folder where I never created the field 'Item_Code' and get the following error:

```
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'GetLayerCount'
```

It seems that the oDS can't access the attribute table at all.

Comment: I wonder... is there a specific reason you use gdal directly to read the file? There are python wrappers around gdal that offer a much easier API to read e.g. shapefiles. E.g. using [geopandas](https://geopandas.org/en/stable/index.html) you can use this single command to read a shapefile `countries_gdf = geopandas.read_file("countries.shp")`.

Comment: Yeah, you are absolutely right. It's just that when I am starting to try escaping from arcpy and embracing the open-source community, the very first choice that came to mind was gdal. I know geopandas for sure, but I didn't learn it initially. However, seeing your comments makes me wonder if it is a more convenient and efficient way to operate geodata. I think I will learn more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you get is because the file failed to open, in which case GDAL (silently) returns None by default. That happens for example when it doesn't exist (incorrect path).

It might be more intuitive to have it crash eagerly, which you can do by calling:

```py
from osgeo import gdal
gdal.UseExceptions()
```

It also seems to become the default starting from GDAL 4 and onward.

The example below shows how to retrieve the attributes as a Pandas DataFrame. Pandas isn't required for this of course, just helpful. You can remove the Pandas part to get a list with a dictionary per feature.

```py
from osgeo import gdal
import pandas as pd

# natural earth example data
shp_path = 'ne_10m_admin_0_countries_lakes.gpkg'

ds = gdal.OpenEx(shp_path)
lyr = ds.GetLayer(0)

df_attr = pd.DataFrame.from_records([{"FID": ft.GetFID()} | dict(ft) for ft in lyr])
```

[image]

Since GDAL 3.6 there's an arrow interface which is orders of magnitude faster compared to the "naive" way shown above. So when performance matters that's certainly worth exploring, details can be found at:
https://gdal.org/development/rfc/rfc86_column_oriented_api.html

edit:

The ogr error codes are:

```py
def is_code(x): return x.startswith("OGRERR")

error_codes = {k: getattr(ogr, k) for k in filter(is_code, dir(ogr))}
```

```py
{
    'OGRERR_CORRUPT_DATA': 5,
    'OGRERR_FAILURE': 6,
    'OGRERR_INVALID_HANDLE': 8,
    'OGRERR_NONE': 0,
    'OGRERR_NON_EXISTING_FEATURE': 9,
    'OGRERR_NOT_ENOUGH_DATA': 1,
    'OGRERR_NOT_ENOUGH_MEMORY': 2,
    'OGRERR_UNSUPPORTED_GEOMETRY_TYPE': 3,
    'OGRERR_UNSUPPORTED_OPERATION': 4,
    'OGRERR_UNSUPPORTED_SRS': 7,
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your heuristic and informative answer, I realized that I forgot to combine the root path with the filename and gdal wasn't operating my existing files actually. LOL. Though I have difficulty understanding the arrow interface and performance stuff, sincerely I appreciate your help. gdal.UseExceptions() is surely important, no wonder it is the default starting as you said.

Comment: By the way, do you know where I can find the standard of the constant in the official documents? Like OGRErr or osgeo.ogr.OGRERR_NONE, I just don't know what their value stands for.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean, just the value of the constants? You can evaluate them in Python (see the edit), or for example at:  
https://gdal.org/java/constant-values.html#org.gdal.ogr.ogrConstants.OGRERR_NONE

Comment: I don't think the arrow interface will offer much improvement for ESRI Shapefiles btw, but for more modern formats like geoparquet/geopackage etc it will.

Comment: The website helps. It is just what I need. The code you use is also amazing, I will try to wield it.